# Recursive Relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I have wrote a recursive code of the type:

```
function(n){
   if n==1:
     return
   else{
   do something
   function(n-1)
}
```

Now I am trying to analyze the complexity

I came to $T(n)=T(n-1)+1$ but how do I solve this kind of recursive relation? master theorem can not be used, I vaguely remember something like:

$$T(n)=T(n-1)+1$$
$$T(n-1)=T(n-2)+1$$
$$T(n-2)=T(n-3)+1$$

So it is of the kind
$$T(n)=T(n-k)+1$$
and then we set $m=n-k$

But I do not remember how to proceed.

Comment: It should $T(n)=T(n-k)+k$. This is an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Your analysis is only correct if the time complexity of "$\mathtt{do   \;something}$" is independent of $n$. If that is the case, then the sum of the arithmetic progression is easily found by thinking about counting on your fingers.

Comment: @Bernard yes that what I meant, the next step it substitution of $n-k$ or something like that, where can I read more about this subject?

Comment: You can take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this
$$T(n) - T(0) = \sum_{k=1}^n T(k) - T(k-1).$$

Comment: Multiplying this by $\frac{n}{2}$ will give use the sum of the arithmetic progression so $\frac{n(T(n)-1)}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n(T(k)-T(k-1)}{2}$ we want to find an expression for $T(n)$ which is not recursive?

Answer (score 2):

By expanding the recursive equation, you can found $T(n) = \Theta(n)$ (by induction).

Comment: If I look at $T(n)-T(n-1)=n$ and then summing it, I get  $T(n)-1=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ or $T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$ how is it $\Theta (n)$?

Comment: @gbox Sorry, you are wrong. $T(n) - T(n-1) = 1$ by your definition.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct so the sum of $\sum T(n)-T(n-1)=T(n)-T(0)=n$